# Find the highest n elements in a list and their locations. Python

Tags: python, performance, list

Recently I was asked to write some code to find the highest n elements in a list and return both the values and the locations.

Can you get any quicker (in terms of execution time) than this?

```
def highest(L, n):
    return sorted(enumerate(L), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[:n]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    M = [102, 56, 2355, 3, 25, 78, 19, 25, 1002, -54, 0, 23, -1]
    r = highest(M,5)
    print r  #[(2, 2355), (8, 1002), (0, 102), (5, 78), (1, 56)]
```

Comment: Quicker? Or shorter? Either way it doesn't seem you have a real question.

Comment: Quicker in terms of execution time, length of the code isn't important unless it effects speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `n` is small compared to the length of the list, `heapq.nlargest` should be faster than sorting the whole list. It's also more readable.

```
def highest(L, n):
    return heapq.nlargest(n, enumerate(L), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

>>> M = [102, 56, 2355, 3, 25, 78, 19, 25, 1002, -54, 0, 23, -1]
>>> highest(M,5)
[(2, 2355), (8, 1002), (0, 102), (5, 78), (1, 56)]
```

This will work in O(N + nlogn) where `N` is the length of the list and `n` is the number of items to return, as opposed to O(NlogN) for sorting.

Comment: I would add that creating a heap is done in linear time, and extracting the largest element is done in constant time. So, this is indeed asymptotically faster than the O(N log N) of the sort from the question.

Comment: @EOL: Extracting (and removing) the largest item is actually logarithmic time. I've added complexity info to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *finding*, by "extracting", not removing… According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants, this is indeed done in constant (not logarithmic) time, if I understand correctly. Now, `heapq.nlargest()` might indeed well remove the largest elements to do its job…

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition, you can use `kth_smallest` in pandas to find the value in O(N).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([102, 56, 2355, 3, 25, 78, 19, 25, 1002, -54, 0, 23, -1.0])
pd.algos.kth_smallest(a, len(a)-5)
```

the code is here:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/algos.pyx#L653

Note: `kth_smallest` returns the value only, but you can scan the array to find the position.

Comment: Thanks @HYRY thats good to know. Have I missed something but this is the smallest right and not the largest?

Comment: kth_smallest and kth_largest is the same algoritm.